# PHP UTF-8 Encoding in HTML Input Box

Tags: php, html, encoding, utf-8, meta-tags

Here what is in database

```
Seilpendel für Tragsysteme
```

now i am loading it into textbox via AJAX but what loads into textbox is

```
Seilpendel f�r Tragsysteme
```

but i want correct string `Seilpendel für Tragsysteme` into inputbox

i have tried

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

but not its working

Comment: is "Seilpendel f�r Tragsysteme" loaded from a database? if so you have to specify the charset for the mysql connection. Also use a font that supports german.

Comment: Run this query after connecting to database: `SET NAMES utf8` and see if it helps.

Comment: "Also use a font that supports german." - lol, I don't think there are any fonts in common use on the web that can't cope with u-umlaut.

Comment: if it was a font issue the result would be a square, not a question mark sign - question mark sign is usually seen when there are page or string encoding issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the db is encoded in UTF8, or use **utf8_encode()** or **utf8_decode()** when loading data from db or when writing back.

Comment: this solution is just a patch - it doesn't fix the real problem that cause it

Comment: Yeah, make sure it's in UTF-8 in the DB. At least when I used PHPMyAdmin, it seemed to default to latin-1-swedish or something like that for me. Whatever tool or config you're using, check it's on utf-8.

Comment: The swedish part is the collation. Google that to know what it means.
As far as I know, swedish it's the choice with the most characters, making it the best choice for everybody. Not sure about it, just a hunch.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way solving this problem is to configure database to use UTF8 as their character encoding in and out.

RUN The following query after connecting to the database, one time and everything should start working.

```
SET NAMES 'utf8';
```

Answer (score 1):

make sure that you also save the file with UTF8 encoding

you can open it in notepad (or even better - notepad++)
and on the "Save As..." popup - select UTF8 instead of the default ANSI

if you're using notepad++ select utf-8 without BOM

if the file's encoding is ok make sure that the connection to the DB is in utf-8 
you can do it by querying:
`SET NAMES 'utf8'`

Comment: i AM TRYING to load it into <input> of html, not in nodepad

Comment: yes, but the `php` file you are writing is saved in some encoding. open it with notepad, and then "Save As the file - in the "save as" window - below the name of the file you will see a drop down to select the encoding of the page - this should also be "UTF-8".